# How to distinguish among CPU, Motherboard and RAM failure

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure

I am getting RAM errors like the following when running both XMP (3200MHz) and non-XMP (2666MHz) profiles:

```
Block Sequential    : testing  56FAILURE: 0xffffffffffffffff != 0xffffffdfffffffff at offset 0x3c2cb1d8.
  Block Sequential    : setting   4FAILURE: 0x707060707070707 != 0x707070707070707 at offset 0x3c72b4e8.
  Bit Spread          : setting 108FAILURE: 0xfffebeffffffffff != 0xfffebfffffffffff at offset 0x3c72b4e8.
testing 119  Bit Flip            : setting 115FAILURE: 0x7272727276727272 != 0x7272727272727272 at offset 0x125e2288.
setting 112  Checkerboard        : testing 122FAILURE: 0xaaaaaaaaaeaaaaaa != 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa at offset 0x125e2288.
testing 144  Bit Spread          : testing 249FAILURE: 0xffffffffefffffff != 0xffffffffebffffff at offset 0x125e2288.
  Bit Spread          : testing  48FAILURE: 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa != 0xaaaaeaaaaaaaaaaa at offset 0x143f9660.
  Bit Spread          : testing  58FAILURE: 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa != 0xaaaaaaaaa8aaaaaa at offset 0x2f292268.
```

The errors continue - I just interrupted the test. The errors happen even if I use XMP voltage (1.35V) when running non-XMP profile (1.2V). And raising the voltage in XMP up to 1.41V doesn't help - the errors still occur.

The error do not occur in single-threaded tests. They only happen when the CPU is 100% loaded (or at least multiple threads are used).

CPU: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3990X (64 physical, 128 logical cores, 2.9GHz stock frequency)

RAM:

- 4 sticks of Crucial Ballistix 2x32GB DDR4 PC4-28800 BL2K32G36C16U4B (3600MHz)
- 4 sticks of Crucial Ballistix 2x32GB DDR4 PC4-25600 BL2K32G32C16U4B (3200MHz)

The sticks are installed in different channel pairs, which can even use different voltage. Each channel can have its own timings. The frequency has to be the same for all RAM.

Motherboard: Gigabyte TRX40 Designare

I use the following Linux/Bash scripts to reproduce the problem:

`parallel-memtester.sh`:

```
set -x
LOG_FILE=memtester-log.txt
N_CORES=128
FREE_MB=$(awk '/^Mem/ {print $4}' <(free -m))
sudo echo Preventing $N_CORES sudo password prompts
rm $LOG_FILE
PER_WORKER=$(( ($FREE_MB - 700) / $N_CORES ))
for i in $(seq 1 $N_CORES)
do
  (sudo memtester ${PER_WORKER}M >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1) &
done
```

`follow-memtester.sh`:

```
tail -f memtester-log.txt | grep -i failure
```

`kill-memtester.sh`:

```
sudo pkill memtester
```

So my question is how to distinguish whether the failures happen due to CPU, motherboard or RAM? I don't have the swap components.

UPDATE:
Modules E37340F1, E37340F5, E37340F3 and E3734104, when installed in A&B channels, run at 3600MHz, but produce failures in the tests. When only 2 modules occupy A2 and B2 slots, there is no XMP if I use E37340F3 and E3734104 - they can only run at 2666MHz and produce no failures at that frequency. The other 2 modules, E37340F1 and E37340F5, run at 3600MHz, but produce failures in Bit Flip test.

Comment: Sounds like a case of an unstable memory overclock. Can you confirm the issue happens when you use the individual pairs at the same desired frequency?

Comment: @Ramhound, there is no overclock beyond XMP. 2666 is the JEDEC frequency for all 8 sticks. 3200 is supported without overclocking by both CPU and motherboard. I checked individual pairs only in single-threaded mode, and they all pass the tests. Let me try multi-threaded tests on a subset of sticks...

Comment: Try them in sets of 4.  All 4 must be running at their supported frequency.  This means when you install the faster set, you will have to adjust the profile, after/before running the slower set.  You have tried running everything at 3200, right? Suspect the problem is the different frequencies. Individually these modules are on the QVL?

Comment: @Ramhound no, these modules are not in QVL. Yes, I tried running them all at 3200 - errors happen. I'll update the question with the rest.

Comment: Test RAM with Memtest86+ or similar utility to scope it out. CPU is very rare to be an issue. For MB - you need to make sure all voltages are as expected.